# Play 2.2.1 application not starting on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have deployed play 2.2.1 [helloworld](https://github.com/vikrant1433/helloworld) (github link) application but it is not working.
here is the link for the helloworld [app](http://vikrant04.herokuapp.com/).
Application is running fine locally.

[image: app running locally]

ProcFile

> web:    play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS

plugin.sbt

> logLevel := Level.Warn
>
> resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
>
> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")

system.properties

> java.runtime.version=1.7

build.properties

> sbt.version=0.13.0

heroku logs

```
Enable Logplex by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

Release v2 created by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

]: Slug compilation started

Set PATH, JAVA_OPTS, SBT_OPTS, REPO config vars by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

Release v5 created by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

Scale to web=1 by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

Release v4 created by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

Release v3 created by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE resource by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

Set DATABASE_URL config vars by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

]: Slug compilation finished

Deploy 4ce7ade by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

Release v6 created by mailtovikrantpro@gmail.com

ash: play: command not found

: Starting process with command `play run --http.port=17894 $PLAY_OPTS`

: State changed from starting to crashed

: State changed from crashed to starting

: Process exited with status 127

ash: play: command not found

]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=serene-plateau-2664.herokuapp.com request_id=e2a4c9df-03f2-4559-8c16-b3d93676ce3a fwd="61.3.30.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

: State changed from starting to crashed

]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=serene-plateau-2664.herokuapp.com request_id=8325f59d-d472-457a-9cbe-53b6a0586088 fwd="61.3.30.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

: Starting process with command `play run --http.port=13540 $PLAY_OPTS`

: Process exited with status 127

]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=serene-plateau-2664.herokuapp.com request_id=d5ebf2fc-d835-4547-98fa-1deda63cf4ab fwd="61.3.30.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=serene-plateau-2664.herokuapp.com request_id=629429d2-a9a3-4a2b-8b1e-37902dac4e35 fwd="61.3.30.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=serene-plateau-2664.herokuapp.com request_id=80d7e8d5-2f52-4b2b-9e98-99745f00d384 fwd="61.3.30.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=serene-plateau-2664.herokuapp.com request_id=2c1cbc02-e23b-41f0-b5f1-adab1353b67b fwd="61.3.30.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I tried restarting the app but no luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `procfile` does not look correct. It should look more like this:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/helloworld -Dhttp.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

Official documentation on this subject: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Production